# using jquery deferred instead of callback

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to resolve an array of task (array is dynamic), these tasks are async and I need to make sure previous task success before the next ask. so far this is what I have:

```
var tasks = ['cleaning', 'washing', 'shopping'];

var index = 0;

while(index < tasks.length) {
  // success => next task
  // fail => exit
  index++;
}

function doTask(name) {
    var d = $.Deferred();
    console.log('doing ' + name);
    setTimeout(function() {
        d.resolve(name + ' is done');
    }, 1000); 
    return d.promise();
}

// my old method
function doTask(name, callback) {
    console.log('doing ' + name);
    setTimeout(function() {
        callback(name + ' is done');
    }, 1000);
}
```

so the output would be

```
// doing cleaning
// cleaning is done
// doing washing
// washing is done
// doing shopping
// shopping is done
```

thanks for the help!

Comment: Deferreds still need callbacks (and recursion instead of loops), the only advantage is that you can `return` from the callback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var tasks = ['cleaning', 'washing', 'shopping'];
var index = 0;

function asyncTasks(tasks_length){
 $.when(doTask(tasks[index])).then(function(res){
   console.dir(res);
   index++;
   if(index<tasks_length){
     asyncTasks(tasks_length);
   } else {return;}
 }, function(){return;})
}

function doTask(name) {
    var d = $.Deferred();
    console.log('doing ' + name);
    setTimeout(function() {
        d.resolve(name + ' is done');
    }, 1000); 
    return d.promise;
}

asyncTasks(tasks.length);
```

Smth like this, not sure in syntax, usially work with angular promises

Comment: Your `asyncTasks` returns no promises?

Answer (score 0):

In your **doTask()** function replace code with `d.promise()` for getting promise object, Code below will execute only in all previous promises are done.

```
var tasks = ['cleaning', 'washing', 'shopping'];

function doTask(name) {
    var d = $.Deferred();
    console.log('doing ' + name);
    setTimeout(function() {
        d.resolve(name + ' is done');
    }, 1000); 
    return d.promise();
}

var d1 =doTask(tasks[0]);
var d2 =doTask(tasks[1]);
var d3 =doTask(tasks[2]);


$.when( d1, d2,d3 ).done(function (w1,w2,w3) {
   console.log(w1,w2,w3);
   // Success call back
});
```

Output:

```
doing cleaning 
doing washing
doing shopping

 cleaning is done
 washing is done
 shopping is done
```

Comment: That's not the output the OP wants.